# Interpretation of PCA explained variance ratio

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, pca

I use the following code:

```
# Fit PCA

pca = PCA(n_components=3)
pca.fit(data)

# Plot
plt.plot(range(0,3), pca.explained_variance_ratio_)
plt.ylabel('Explained Variance')
plt.xlabel('Principal Components')
plt.title('Explained Variance Ratio')
plt.show()
pca.explained_variance_ratio_
```

From this I obtain the following graph:

[image]

and `array([0.92540219, 0.06055593, 0.01404188])`

What I dont understand is why it is showing just two principal components? And should it be 92.54% (of info explained by 1st component), while in the graph it is less the 20%? Please, help me with this misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is showing all threes components. The values of pca.explained_variance_ratio_ are plotted in your graph at 0, 1 and 2 on the x axis.
First value is at (0, 0.92540219), second at (1, 0.06055593) and last at (2, 0.01404188).

Answer (score 1):

In fact, as [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html) states, `explained_variance_ratio_` returns the percentage of variance explained by each of the selected components. So, it does exactly what you expect, and your graph shows that.

This way should be a bit clearer:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

plt.plot(range(0,3), [0.92540219, 0.06055593, 0.01404188])
plt.ylabel('Explained Variance')
plt.xlabel('Principal Components')
plt.xticks(range(0,3),
           ["1st comp", "2nd comp", "3rd comp"], rotation=60)
plt.title('Explained Variance Ratio')
plt.show()
```

[image]